# "weight" input in glm.nb function in R. How exactly does the weight affect the likelihood?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, maximum-likelihood, negative-binomial-distribution, exponential-family

I would like to understand how the weight argument of `glm.nb` is affecting the likelihood function.
I understand that `glm.nb` find the MLE in an alternating iteration process where for a given theta the GLM is fitted using `glm()` with `family=negative.binomial(theta=theta.this.iteration)` and for fixed means the theta parameter is estimated using score and information iterations.

Regarding the weight input, the `help(glm.nb)` only says that it is passed to `glm()` (See below).

> `formula`, `data`, `weights`, `subset`, `na.action`, `start`, `etastart`, `mustart`, `control`, `method`,     `model`, `x`, `y`, `contrasts`, `...` arguments for the `glm()` function. Note that these exclude `family` and `offset` (but `offset()` can be used).

So I am assuming that the `weights` in `glm.nb` is directly passed to `glm()` with `family=negative.binomial(theta=theta.this.iteration)`.

Regarding the weights, `help(glm)` says that the dispersion parameter is rescaled as $\phi=\phi^*/w_i$ (see below):

> Non-`NULL` weights can be used to indicate that different observations have different dispersions (with the values in weights being inversely proportional to the dispersions); or equivalently, when the elements of weights are positive integers $w_i$, that each response $y_i$ is the mean of $w_i$ unit-weight observations. For a binomial GLM prior weights are used to give the number of trials when the response is the proportion of successes: they would rarely be used for a Poisson GLM.

In my understanding, the negative binomial distribution with given theta (denoted $\theta$) belongs to exponential family with a dispersion parameter = 1 (is my understanding correct?). 
To see this,

Suppose a random variable $y_i$ has a negative binomial distribution with mean $\mu_i$ and variance $\mu_i + \frac{1}{\theta}\mu_i^2$ then its density is:

$$
f(y_i;\mu_i,\theta) = \frac{\Gamma(\theta + y_i)}{ \Gamma(\theta) y_i ! } 
\left(\frac{\mu_i}{\mu_i+\theta}\right)^{y_i}
\left(\frac{\theta}{\mu_i+\theta}\right)^{\theta}.
$$

If $\theta$ is know, then this negative binomial distribution is from the exponential family as:

\begin{align*}
f(y_i;\mu_i,\theta) 
&= \exp\left(
y_i\log
\left(\frac{\mu_i}{\mu_i+\theta}\right)
+
\theta \log
\left(\frac{\theta}{\mu_i+\theta}\right)
+
\log\left[
\frac{\Gamma(\theta + y_i)}{ \Gamma(\theta) y_i ! } 
\right]
\right)\\
&= \exp\left(
\frac{m_i}{\phi}\left(y_i\kappa_i-b(\kappa_i)\right)+c(y_i;\phi)
\right)
\end{align*}
where: 
\begin{align*}
\kappa_i&=\log\left(\frac{\mu_i}{\mu_i+\theta} \right)\\
\phi&=1\\ 
m_i&=1\\
b(\kappa_i) 
&= - \theta\log(1-e^{\kappa_i})\\
c(y_i;\phi)
&=\log\left[
\frac{\Gamma(\theta + y_i)}{ \Gamma(\theta) y_i ! } 
\right]
\end{align*}

so the dispersion parameter $\phi=1$!! Therefore the weighted negative binomial density can be obtained by simply letting $\phi=\phi^*/w_i$:

\begin{align}
f(y_i;\mu_i,\theta,w_i) 
&= \exp \left(w_i \frac{m_i}{\phi^*} (y_i\kappa_i - b(\kappa_i)) + c(y_i;\phi^*/w_i)\right)
\\
&= \exp\left(
w_iy_i\log
\left(\frac{\mu_i}{\mu_i+\theta}\right)
+
w_i\theta \log
\left(\frac{\theta }{\mu_i+\theta }\right)
+
\log\left[
\frac{\Gamma(\theta + y_i)}{ \Gamma(\theta) y_i ! } 
\right]
\right)\\
\end{align}
The last term does NOT depend on $w_i$ because $c(y_i;\phi)$ function does not depend on $\phi$ which leads to $c(y_i;\phi^*/w_i)=c(y_i;\phi)$.

**So I originally believed that glm.nb is iteratively maximizing the above weighted likelihood $f(y_i;\mu_i,\theta,w_i)$.** In the step where $\theta$ is maximized for given $\mu_i$, `glm.nb` use internal function named `theta.ml`. By closely looking at this function, I found that it uses a score function defined as:

```
  score <- function(n, th, mu, y, w) sum(w * (digamma(th + 
    y) - digamma(th) + log(th) + 1 - log(th + mu) - (y + 
    th)/(mu + th)))
```

This looks to be the score function of the likelihood:

\begin{align}
f^R(y_i;\mu_i,\theta,w_i)=
 \exp\left(
w_iy_i\log
\left(\frac{\mu_i}{\mu_i+\theta}\right)
+
w_i\theta \log
\left(\frac{\theta }{\mu_i+\theta }\right)
+
w_i \log\left[
\frac{\Gamma(\theta + y_i)}{ \Gamma(\theta) y_i ! } 
\right]
\right),\\
\end{align} 
which is different from $f(y_i;\mu_i,\theta,w_i)$.

**Is glm.nb maximizing $f(y_i;\mu_i,\theta,w_i)$ or $^Rf(y_i;\mu_i,\theta,w_i)$**?

Comment: Have you supplied `trace=TRUE`? One result from binomial (and poisson and other) likelihoods is that `glm(y ~ x, family=binomial, weights=w)` and `glm(rep.int(y, w) ~ rep.int(x, w), family=binomial)` produce identical results up to the deviance when `w` is frequency weights. If the same held for `glm.nb`, I'd be inclined to say it's a likelihood of the $f^R$ form.